# RichTextBox строки

Tags: c#

Возник такой вопрос. Есть в RichTextBox у меня две строки, и надо при нажатии кнопки добавить в первую строку RichTextBox число. Я сделал по аналогии с TextBox.

```
richTextBox1.Lines[0] += "1";
```

Однако действие не выполняется. Для наглядности привожу пример с TextBox.

```
textBox1.Text += "1";
```

В чём проблема, что здесь за тонкость?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тонкость в том, что свойство `Lines` каждый раз возвращает новый массив строк. Ваш код меняет одну из строк в изменённом массиве, который с исходными данными уже не связан.

По идее, так должно работать:

1. Сохранить массив в локальную переменную
2. Изменить нужную строку в массиве через эту переменную
3. Изменённый массив снова присвоить свойству `Lines`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы добавить текст к richTextBox надо вызывать AppendText("текст"), а вот чтобы изменить конкретную строку - вот тут не знаю, самому интересно.

Полезно читать MSDN (ремарки): Lines по дефолту read-only, для изменения надо делать так:

```
richTextBox1.Lines = new string[] { "строка1", "строка2" };
```